# How to add "open in new tab" option in CkEditor

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Now, we can only add link. But our client is looking for an option in Ckeditor for adding an option to addition of "Open in NEW tab" option with Link.

[image]

Do we have any module or any trick for solution of this issue ?

**OR**

Do we have to alter CkEditor module ?

Comment: Customer need an option at UI end.

Comment: Dev needs to read **all** other answers thoroughly.